# Problem with invoice its show #!trpst#trp-gettext data

Tags: plugins

I hope you all doing well, with the last update I am facing some problem with my invoice during order in English Language. As you can see in link attched of screenshot its show !trpst#trp-gettext data-trpgettextoriginal=5689#!trpen#W, my primary web language is Macedonina, and there is working everything fine, in English during invoice generation has problem, other part is everything fine.

Does anyone has any idea how to fix this.

Kind regards

https://prnt.sc/0ukQ_25GzqZX

Comment: I'd guess this is a problem with TranslatePress, e.g. [a similar error report here](https://wordpress.org/support/topic/error-trpsttrp-gettext-data-trpgettextoriginal/). You should probably ask them about it - they'll know better than we will.

Comment: I have already opened the ticked, but unfortunately thay still hasn't responded my ticket, its urgent to solve, because I have to lunch the site. I am really stuck